# Objective-C implementation of Ruby "chunk"

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

I have an Objective-C application where I'm trying to sort an NSArray while grouping the array elements that have equal sort values. Ideally, I would generate a new array of sets, where each set in the new array contains one or more of the original array elements and all of the elements in each set have equal sort values. It would work similarly to the [Ruby "chunk" method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)

To give an example, imagine I had an NSArray containing items whose sort values are equivalent to the following:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

I would want the new array to contain 9 sets with sort values that look like:

```
[ (1), (2), (3, 3, 3), (4), (5, 5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ]
```

In Ruby I would be able to first sort the array and then chunk it to get what I want. I'm trying to come up with a reasonably efficient way to do it in Objective-C.

I could set up a dictionary containing each possible sort value as a key with an NSSet as the value for each key. I could then loop through the initial array, computing the sort value for each item, finding the appropriate key for that sort value, and updating its set as I go. I could finally sort the contents of that dictionary to get a list of sorted sets.

I could do all that, but it seems like there should be a better way that I'm missing. Also, the values I'm sorting by could actually be floating-point values, so using them as keys in a dictionary is likely to be of limited value.

Can anyone think of a more clever way of doing this? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: A "set" having multiple elements that are equal does not reflect the usual meaning of that word.

Comment: A fair point: I was trying to simplify the problem and got a little careless with my wording and my example. In actuality, I would be creating sets of different objects that have equal values from a sorting perspective. I have edited my description to be a little more clear.

Comment: I see, the "sort values" that determine membership are the result of some kind of key function, then?

Comment: Yes, more or less. I actually need to use this sort in several different ways so I compute the sort value using a selector that is invoked to compute the sort value. In many cases though, the sort selector I invoke just calls the object's valueForKey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the number of times the objects occur, then Kurt's answer is pretty good. If you actually need the chunking, though, this should work:

```
NSArray *original = @[@1, @3, @5, @7, @9, @8, @5, @3, @2, @4, @3, @6];
NSMutableArray *chunked = [NSMutableArray array];

NSNumber *current = nil;
for (NSNumber *number in [original sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]) {
    if (![number isEqual:current]) {
        [chunked addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:number]];
        current = number;
    } else {
        [[chunked lastObject] addObject:number];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", chunked);
```

Unless I've missed something, this isn't computationally complex, and should be slightly more efficient than Tim's original method (no need for dictionaries, sets, or hashing). There's one sort involved (in fast enumeration, the container — the part after `in` — is evaluated only once), and you iterate over the sorted array once. `NSMutableArray` insertion is `O(1)` at either end, so worst case should be `O(n)` because of the iteration.

---

**Actually:** on further review, the following code runs a lot faster for large sets of numbers. It's slightly more convoluted, but runs more efficiently.

```
NSArray *original = @[@1, @3, @5, @7, @9, @8, @5, @3, @2, @4, @3, @6];
NSMutableArray *chunked = [NSMutableArray array];

NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:original];
for (NSNumber *number in countedSet) {
    NSMutableArray *chunk = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger count = [set countForObject:number];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        [chunk addObject:number];
    }

    [chunked addObject:chunk];
}

[chunked sortUsingComparator:^(NSArray *a1, NSArray *a2) {
    return [a1[0] compare:a2[0]];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", chunked);
```

With `10000000` random numbers, the first implementation runs in about `12.27` seconds, while the second runs in `0.92` seconds. Go figure.

The second method has a drawback in that the chunks it creates are all duplicates of the same object; if that presents problems for you (in the general case, it could be problematic for memory management, or if your objects can be considered 'equal' in a sense, even if all their properties aren't exactly so), then use the first method. Otherwise, this'll work better for you.

---

**Additional clarification:** on further thought, I knew something was fishy in the time differences between the two methods, and I was right. If you have a lot of variation in your dataset (with very few repeated numbers), method 2 will run far, far more slowly; variation in numbers doesn't affect method 1 much. For many repeated numbers, method 2 will be pretty quick, but if your dataset is completely random, you'd be better off using method 1.

Here's the code I'm using to test these two: http://pastebin.com/9syEyiyM

Comment: I think your first method would work best for me. As I clarified in the original post, I am really not trying to create sets of identical NSNumber objects, I am trying to create sets of different objects that have identical NSNumber sort values. Your second approach doesn't seem like it would work for me, but the first would.

Comment: Okay, great! Glad to have helped. :)
I wanted to go through the process of analyzing these and offering suggestions for both just because I assume you're not the only one out there with this problem, and in case someone stumbles across this answer, I wanted to make it general enough to help them as well.

Comment: I tried a number of approaches to this, using index sets, dictionaries, nssets, block enumeration - none led to as fast results nor as straightforward of code as your first approach. [See my generalization here](https://gist.github.com/cveazey/958a8959a4945c614c9d).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a single `NSCountedSet` to store all the keys and the count of each one?

```
NSArray *sourceArray = @[ @1, @3, @5, @7, @9, @8, @5, @3, @2, @4, @3, @6 ];
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:sourceArray];

NSArray* sortedKeys = [[countedSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
for (NSNumber *key in sortedKeys) {
    NSUInteger count = [countedSet countForObject:key];
    NSLog(@"Key: %@ count: %ld", key, (unsigned long)count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this won't solve my problem. In an effort to simplify the explanation of the problem I wasn't as clear as I should have been. I've updated my description to clarify. What I really need is sets of distinct objects whose sort values are equal. NSCountedSet wouldn't give me that.